# Angular2 scrollable content

Tags: jquery, angular, perfect-scrollbar

I used [Perfect Scrollbar](https://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/) and then I started using Angular 2, but I cannot find the similar addition. What would be correct way to implement perfect scrollbar in Angular 2 project?

I followed [this great example](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/using-jquery-with-angular-2.0) but I am kind a lost how to change in `ngOnInit()`

```
jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).draggable({containment:'#draggable-parent'});
```

to this=>

```
$(function() {
  $('#Demo').perfectScrollbar();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could initialize perfect scrollbar within a custom directive with vanilla js (since it supports it ;-)) like this:

```
import Ps from 'perfect-scrollable';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ps]'
})
export class PsDirective {
  constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    Ps.initialize(this.elementRef.nativeElement);
  }
}
```

You can use / apply it like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app'
  template: `
    <div ps class="container">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .content {
      background-image: url('https://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/azusa.jpg');
      width: 1280px;
      height: 720px;
    }

    .container {
      position: relative;
      margin: 0px auto;
      padding: 0px;
      width: 600px;
      height: 400px;
    }
  `],
  directives: [ PsDirective ]
})
export class App {
}
```

The library must have been configured before this way (css and SystemJS):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.perfect-scrollbar/0.6.11/css/perfect-scrollbar.min.css"/>

<script>
  System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript', 
    typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true }, 
    map: {
      'perfect-scrollable': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.perfect-scrollbar/0.6.11/js/min/perfect-scrollbar.min.js'
    },
    packages: {
      'app': {
        defaultExtension: 'ts'
      }
    } 
  });
  System.import('app/main')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/S8DJpHFVNFioklTl1xg6?p=preview.

Comment: Hello i tried it but it is saying perfect-scrollbar has no default export

Comment: You can either write a type definition file for perfect-scrollbar or you can use [Angular2-drag-scroll](https://github.com/bfwg/angular2-drag-scroll) which is an Angular2 library for dragging content scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

[Angular2-drag-scroll](https://github.com/bfwg/angular2-drag-scroll) is the library you are looking

Usage example:

```
<style>
  .demo-one {
    height: 260px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
</style>

<div drag-scroll drag-scroll-y-disabled="true" scrollbar-hidden="true" >
  <img *ngFor="let image of imagelist" [src]="'assets/img/' + image" />
</div>
```

I'm applying "drag-scroll" to the div so everything in side of this div will be 
draggable and has the attribute overflow: scroll etc.

Setting "drag-scroll-y-disabled" to true will disable y-axis scrolling/dragging.

Setting "scrollbar-hidden" to true will hide the scroll bar.

[image: Scroll]

Github page: https://github.com/bfwg/angular2-drag-scroll

demo site: https://bfwg.github.io/angular2-drag-scroll/

Comment: This is deprecated with angular 4.

Comment: @KrishnaKarki The latest version is compatible with Angular 4.